# How can I add a dictionary to an array using Swift?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, swift

I'm trying to add a dictionary containing properties of people into an array, but it's not working.  I'm getting the following error:

`[(Any)] is not identical to UInt8`

Here is my code:

```
var people = [Any]()

class Database {
    class func addPerson(dict: [String : Any]) -> Void {
        people += dict
    }
}

Database.addPerson(["name" : "Fred"])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+=` operator on `Array` corresponds to `Array.extend` which takes a `SequenceType` and not an individual element. If you wrap `dict` in an `Array`, then `+=` will work:

```
people += [dict]
```

However, it's simpler and probably more efficient to use the `append` function instead:

```
people.append(dict)
```

**Side note:**

I'm not sure why you're using `Any` as the `Array`'s element type and the `Dictionary`'s value type (and maybe you have a good reason), but you should typically avoid that if at all possible. In this case I'd declare `dict` as `[String: String]` and `people` as `[[String: String]]`:

```
var people = [[String: String]]()

class Database {
    class func addPerson(dict: [String : String]) -> Void {
        people.append(dict)
    }
}

Database.addPerson(["name" : "Fred"])
```

If you need to be able to store multiple types in your `Dictionary`, there are a few ways you can do that.

1. Use an `NSDictionary` directly.
2. Declare the `Dictionary` as `[String: AnyObject]`.
3. Use an [`enum` with associated values](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-XID_227) as the value type *(this is usually the best option in Swift if you only need to support a few types because everything stays strongly typed)*.

Quick example of using an `enum` (there are quite a few examples of this technique in other SO questions):

```
enum DictValue {
    case AsString(String)
    case AsInt(Int)
}

var people = [[String: DictValue]]()

class Database {
    class func addPerson(dict: [String : DictValue]) -> Void {
        people.append(dict)
    }
}

Database.addPerson(["name" : DictValue.AsString("Fred")])
Database.addPerson(["name" : DictValue.AsInt(1)])
```

Comment: As a side note, is it possible to accept multiple types into a dictionary?  ex `[String: String or Int]()`

Comment: There are 2 ways to do that: use `NSDictionary` or declare the dictionary as `[String : AnyObject]`. In both cases, values can be **any** reference type (so not restricted to string and int only)

Comment: There are the two methods that @Antonio mentioned and one other. I edited my answer with some more info.

Answer (score 1):

There is not built in operator for that I guess. You can use:

```
people.append(dict)
// or
people += [dict as Any]
```